# Outlook Add-ins manifest and Installer folder VSTO

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm developing an outlook addins vsto using visual studio 2010,

When I publish my project I found a new install folder inside "Application Files\MyAddin_version\Installer\MyAddin.exe.deply"

This is a new file with the deploy, before I was able to deploy without this file.

My question, what setting in my build generate this file?

The problem every time I build my project now I found in the manifest file the new entry:

I'm pretty sure the entry was not found in the old builds, I didn't change the code, but I was trying to change the build and publish, switching between local publish and UNC and http.
 (Need to remove this new entry, don't need it every time i build, it causes problem.)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was a bug in my solution, some files were marked as content in the build actions.